# std::for_each, calling member function with reference parameter

Tags: c++, stl, pass-by-reference

I have a container of pointers which I want to iterate over, calling a member function which has a parameter that is a reference. How do I do this with STL?

My current solution is to use boost::bind, and boost::ref for the parameter.

```
// Given:
// void Renderable::render(Graphics& g)
//
// There is a reference, g, in scope with the call to std::for_each
//
std::for_each(
  sprites.begin(),
  sprites.end(),
  boost::bind(&Renderable::render, boost::ref(g), _1)
);
```

A related question (from which I derived my current solution from) is [boost::bind with functions that have parameters that are references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470040/boostbind-with-functions-that-have-parameters-that-are-references). This specifically asks how to do this with boost. I am asking how it would be done *without* boost.

**Edit**: There is a way to do this same thing without using any `boost`. By using `std::bind` and friends the same code can be written and compiled in a C++11-compatible compiler like this:

```
std::for_each(
  sprites.begin(),
  sprites.end(),
  std::bind(&Renderable::render, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(g))
);
```

Comment: boost::bind(&Renderable::render, _1, boost::ref(g)) should probably be boost::bind(&Renderable::render, boost::ref(g), _1 )

Comment: @carleeto Good catch. Fixed after 4 years of being wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the design of `<functional>`. You either have to use boost::bind or tr1::bind.

Comment: yep, sadly :( more information on this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2000/n1245.ps and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#106 which apparently never got into the standard. But it's in the next one :)

Comment: Yes, the references-to-references problems was exactly my issue. Thanks for the info!