# Does boost::bind() copy parameters by reference or by value?

Tags: c++, valgrind, boost-bind

Why does valgrind's DRD tool complaines "Conflicting load by thread ... at size 4": about such code:

```
void SomeFunction(const int& value)
{
    boost::bind(..., value); /* <-- complaines on this line
                                with last backtrace function "new(int)" */
}
```

Does boost::bind() stores values by reference or value?

Comment: if it fails _on the line of the bind_ it is obviously a problem at bind time, so whether bind sotres a copy or a reference is irrelevant then

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By value. [1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html)

But you can make it [copy by ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html) instead:

```
void SomeFunction(const int& value)
{
    boost::bind(..., boost::ref(value)); 
    boost::bind(..., boost::cref(value)); // by const ref
}
```

[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html#Purpose

> a copy of the value of i is stored into the function object.  boost::ref and boost::cref can be used to make the function object store a reference to an object, rather than a copy: 
>   int i = 5;
>
> bind(f, ref(i), _1);
>
> bind(f, cref(42), _1);

Comment: So why then DRD complaines about "new(int)"?

Comment: @Slav: How am I to know? Post more code so I can run it and see for myself :) I'm happy to help, but it's not enough code. Not by a mile