# why is this program using boost::ref

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, boost-ref

> The Ref library is a small library that is useful for passing
>   references to function templates (algorithms) that would usually take
>   copies of their arguments.

from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp

in 
call deliver -

```
  void deliver(const chat_message& msg)
  {
    recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
      recent_msgs_.pop_front();

    std::for_each(participants_.begin(), participants_.end(),
        boost::bind(&chat_participant::deliver, _1, boost::ref(msg)));
  }
```

if the

```
void deliver(const chat_message& msg)
```

in another class is taking message by reference then why is boost::ref used at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::bind` makes a copy of its inputs, so if `boost::ref` is not used in this case, a copy of the `chat_message` will be made. So it seems the authors of the code want to avoid that copy (at the cost of instantiating a `boost::ref` object or two). This could make sense if `chat_message` is large or expensive to copy. But it would make more sense to use a `boost::cref`, since the original is passed by const reference, and the call should not modify the passed message.

**Note**: the above applies to `std::bind` and `std::tr1::bind`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397092/boostbind-copies-by-reference-or-by-value

Answer (score 0):

> The arguments that bind takes are copied and held internally by the
>   returned function object. For example, in the following code:
>
> int i = 5;
>
> bind(f, i, _1); a copy of the value of i is stored into the function
>   object. boost::ref and boost::cref can be used to make the function
>   object store a reference to an object, rather than a copy:

from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html