# Relaying a signal with boost.signals2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

As can be seen in the code below (implemented as an illustration of the problem), I'm trying to send a signal from an inner class to a mid class, which will relay it to an outer class.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class inner {
       public:
    template <class T>
    void register_callback(boost::function<void(T *)> cb, T *obj)
    {
        sig_inner_.connect(boost::bind(cb, boost::ref(obj)));
    }

    void trigger()
    {
        std::cout << "inner" << std::endl;
        sig_inner_();
    }

       private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig_inner_;
};

class mid {
       public:
    mid() { inner_obj.register_callback<mid>(&mid::handle_sig_mid, this); }
    template <class T>
    void register_callback(boost::function<void(T *)> cb, T *obj)
    {
        sig_mid_.connect(boost::bind(cb, boost::ref(obj)));
    }

    void trigger() { sig_mid_(); }
    void inner_trigger() { inner_obj.trigger(); }
    void handle_sig_mid()
    {
        std::cout << "mid" << std::endl;
        trigger();
    }

       private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig_mid_;
    inner inner_obj;
};

class outer {
       public:
    outer() { mid_obj.register_callback<outer>(&outer::handle_sig_outer, this); }
    void inner_trigger() { mid_obj.inner_trigger(); }
       private:
    mid mid_obj;
    void handle_sig_outer() { std::cout << "outer" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    outer outer_obj;
    outer_obj.inner_trigger();
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of the desired result of:

```
inner
mid
outer
```

When running the program, what actually happens is:

```
inner
mid
mid
```

Followed by a crash.

I already noticed that the address of 'this' is different in the handler than what I would expect in a regular method, but I don't know how work around that.

The only solution I found for this was connecting a signal in the outer class to its handler, and then storing the pointer(unique_ptr, in this case) in the inner class, thus avoiding the need to relay it, but it doesn't feel like a safe way to use signals.

I'm kind of new to c++, and to boost in particular, so I don't really know how trigger callbacks in the outer class from the inner class in a clean and safe way.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I turned the solution into a sort of "observer" and "observable" classes that can be plugged in using inheritance:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ed3265edfa47ba1

I bet this could be done much better, but I thought I should share the end product of what I initially tried to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- When you bind to the `boost::ref(obj)` you make the bind-expression hold a reference to the function parameter, which goes out of scope at the exit from `register_callback`. (See [Does boost::bind() copy parameters by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6397092/85371))

  Just bind to the pointer itself, which makes the bind-expression hold a copy of the pointer itself.
- It's important to be aware of lifetime issues when registering callbacks. In general, you must unregister before destroying any bound object in the signal slot.

  In your example this doesn't really occur, because the connected slots all exist in member objects. This means that the slots get destructed before the outer object(s) disappear.

  However, if something gets copied/moved that breaks down. The usual pattern to combat this is to use `scoped_connection`s.

Let me show my suggestions in two steps:

#### Simplify: Bind early, Signals2 Does Type Erasure For You

There's no need to template `register_callback` because you type-erase the object type `T` immediately using `bind` and the nullary signal slot.

So, instead make it take an arbitrary nullary and do the bind in the caller? In fact, prefer to use a lambda at the caller.

```
template <class F> void register_callback(F&& f) {
    sig_inner_.connect(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

And then

```
mid() { inner_obj.register_callback([this] { handle_sig_mid(); }); }
```

### Lifetimes and Signals2: Connections

Instead of using the heavy-weight option and using `enable_shared_from_this()` with dynamic allocation everywhere, use the library facilities: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html

> **Note** In your example, using `shared_from_this()` is out of the question because it's not valid inside the constructor.

My suggestion:

```
template <class F> boost::signals2::scoped_connection register_callback(F&& f) {
    return sig_inner_.connect(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

And then

```
mid() { _connection = inner_obj.register_callback([this] { handle_sig_mid(); }); }
```

Make `_connection` a member:

```
boost::signals2::scoped_connection _connection;
```

This way, the slots get disconnected when the containing class is destructed.

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e73500ec4bc475a3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class inner {
  public:
    template <class F> boost::signals2::scoped_connection register_callback(F&& f) {
        return sig_inner_.connect(std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    void trigger() {
        std::cout << "inner" << std::endl;
        sig_inner_();
    }

  private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig_inner_;
};

class mid {
  public:
    mid() { _connection = inner_obj.register_callback([this] { handle_sig_mid(); }); }

    template <class F> boost::signals2::scoped_connection register_callback(F&& f) {
        return sig_mid_.connect(std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    void trigger() { sig_mid_(); }
    void inner_trigger() { inner_obj.trigger(); }
    void handle_sig_mid() {
        std::cout << "mid" << std::endl;
        trigger();
    }

  private:
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection _connection;
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig_mid_;
    inner inner_obj;
};

class outer {
  public:
    outer() { _connection = mid_obj.register_callback([this] { handle_sig_outer(); }); }
    void inner_trigger() { mid_obj.inner_trigger(); }

  private:
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection _connection;
    mid mid_obj;
    void handle_sig_outer() { std::cout << "outer" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    outer outer_obj;
    outer_obj.inner_trigger();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
inner
mid
outer
```

Comment: As a bonus: here's a version that writes the same without a single template declaration: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a937c9f2ceb3c7e8 (It could in theory be slightly less efficient, but I wager it's on par/better than the original code that delayed the bind to completely down-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Thanks! That was extremely informative. You also significantly increased my reading list for now.

Comment: That's the proper way to learn. I can attest from personal experience that the effort repays itself. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have a handler to call, pass it an instance of a `std::shared_ptr` of the current class instance. You can accomplish that by public inheritance of [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). This way your instance of `mid` will be kept alive until the handler has finished.

```
class mid : public std::enable_shared_from_this<mid>
{
    mid()
    {
        inner_obj.register_callback<mid>(&mid::handle_sig_mid, shared_from_this());
    }

    //...
};
```

Comment: Shared-from-this is not an answer to everything, and I'd say it's a-typical in Signals2

Comment: Besides, the code you show is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this (c++17 makes it defined, but guaranteed to throw)