# boost::bind() creates many copies of the argument

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I was working with boost::bind (Boost 1.64.0 and gcc 8.3.0) to create a callable object and noticed an interesting feature
An object passed in bind constructor as an argument to a wrappable function is copied multiple times.
Even if the object is wrapped in std::move(). Although std::bind works as expected.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <functional>

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Create\n";
    }

    Test(const Test& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy\n";
    }

    Test(Test&& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Move\n";
    }

    ~Test() noexcept
    {

    }
};

void foo(Test& t)
{

}


int main()
{
    Test t;
    auto f = boost::bind(&foo, t);
    f();
}
```

Output for boost::bind(&foo, t);

```
Create
Copy
Copy
Copy
Copy
Copy
```

Output for boost::bind(&foo, std::move(t));

```
Create
Move
Copy
Copy
Copy
Copy
```

Output for std::bind(&foo, t);

```
Create
Copy
```

Output for std::bind(&foo, std::move(t));

```
Create
Move
```

- Why does boost copy so many times?
- Is it correct to pass rvalue as an argument to bind (in both cases of implementation)?
- Do I understand correctly that bind will move the object to its context and store it, and when foo is called, passes it as an lvalue reference?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design.

To avoid it, avoid copies of the bind adaptor and use `ref`:

```
auto f = boost::bind(&foo, boost::ref(t));
```

---

- Why does boost copy so many times?

Mostly due to the fact that your constructor cannot be elided. Keep it an aggregate or trivial constructor and it doesn't happen.

- Is it correct to pass rvalue as an argument to bind (in both cases of implementation)?

Yes, bind captures arguments by value (unless you use explicit `ref()` or `cref()` to create `reference_wrapper`s.)

- Do I understand correctly that bind will move the object to its context and store it, and when foo is called, passes it as an lvalue reference?

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397107/85371)

---

## Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d6480a52291a5f0)**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    Test()                       { std::cout << "Create\n"; } 
    Test(const Test& /*unused*/) { std::cout << "Copy\n";   } 
    Test(Test&& /*unused*/)      { std::cout << "Move\n";   } 
    ~Test() noexcept             {                          } 
};

void foo(Test& /*unused*/) {}

int main() {
    Test t;
    auto f = boost::bind(&foo, boost::ref(t));
    f();
}
```

Prints:

```
Create
```

Comment: Many thanks. But what if **t** is a local object, and **f** must be executed in another thread?

Comment: Then you can alleviate at least one copy by moving (`bind(&foo, std::move(t))`), and if you use types with constructors without weird side-effects, the compiler will optimize others.

Comment: Compare https://godbolt.org/z/3SVbT2 (you can see the compiler just emits all the `operator<<` because it /has/ to, but it's all inlined), vs. https://godbolt.org/z/dS0bRO.

Comment: It would be great if you can add why boost was designed in such a way. For me `std` is doing copy once.

Comment: Finally, you can get with the times: https://godbolt.org/z/ulFg0G or even just: https://godbolt.org/z/9NzU_j (`bind` is legacy and C++11 is a decade old).

Comment: @abhiarora Ah. In that respect, I do not know the answer (why is implementation X different from implementation Y). My *guess* is that the standard implementation  is taking advantage of rvalue-semantics (because `std::bind` was only introduced in C++11, whereas Boost Bind predates it by many many years).

Comment: So, in comparison, std should be preferred to boost for bind?

Comment: Maybe. I'd say `std::bind` should not be used. Use the language feature instead (lambdas) so the compiler doesn't have to optimize through thick layers of library abstractions.